# I need to sort out this algorithm

Tags: javascript

could you please your help.

how to answer this question ?

I need your help thinks

```
function factorial(n) {
  if (n === 0) { 
    return 1;
  } else {
    return n * n  ;
  }
}

factorial(6)
```

this is not right.. i need to use writing code with Loop javascript.

> Get the factorial of n. The inheritance of n is the number 1 through n multiplied by all numbers.

#### example)

answer should be like this

```
factorial(4); // => 24
factorial(5); // => 120
```

Comment: Hint: `n * n` is n^2. You want to calc factorial(n) which is something else;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a simple for loop.

```
var answer = 1;
for(var i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    answer *= i;
}

return answer;
```

You can also do this recursively by multiplying your input by the result of the previous value.

```
function factorial(n){
    if(n <= 1) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```